# Delete files with special characters in filenames

Tags: php, solaris, filenames, character, unlink

I need to delete old files with special characters in filenames like space,`,`,`(`,`)`,`!` and so on via PHP. Classic `unlink($filename)` does not work for these files. How can I transform filenames to filenames which accepts unlink function and filesystem? It's running on a Solaris machine and I don't have another access to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you constructing the `$filename`? unlink should work on any filename with special characters if you do the normal escaping on it. e.g.

for a file with a name of `this has, various/wonky !characters in it`, then

```
 $filename = 'this has\, various\/wonky \!characters in it';
 unlink($filename);
```

should work.

Comment: Filename is output from readdir command, i compare if files in directory is used id database and if not, delete it. I don't escape this filename, is there a way to auto-espace it? I need to add that there can be also cp-1250 characters like "ž ľ č š" and so on...

Comment: Well, if you're dealing with filenames that contain shell metacharacters, then you do need to escape those. Unlink won't know that a `/` in the filename is actually part of the filename and not the directory separator unless you escape it yourself.

Comment: The cp-1250 characters shouldn't be a problem, unless for whatever reason PHP and/or your glibc are working on a different codepage/charset at the time. It's possible (but not likely) that one of the accented chars in the "foreign" charset could by chance map to one of the shell metacharacters, like `/` and then you're back to square one.

Comment: Solaris filesystems don't allow / in filenames, it's always a directory separator, so there's no reason to escape it.

Answer (score 1):

unlink accepts any valid string and will try to delete the file in that string.

```
unlink('/home/user1/"hello(!,');
```

Perhaps you are not properly escaping certain characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can also find all needed files and unlink them using RegexIterator:

```
<?php

$dir  = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('.');
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir);
$regex = new RegexIterator($iterator, '/(^.*[\s\.\,\(\)\!]+.*)/', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);

foreach ($regex as $file) {
        if (is_file($file[0])) {
                print "Unlink file {$file[0]}\n";
                unlink($file[0]);
        }
}
```

This code snippet recursively traverse all directories from current ('.') and matches all files by regex '/(^.*[\s\,.()!]+.*)/', then delete them.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it in Linux is to use absolute paths, like "rm ./filename" that is dot slash.

You can also use escape charachters. Like "rm \-filename" that is - backspash hyphen.