# unlink php error with & in file name

Tags: php, unlink

I can't unlink file with php if there is & in file name.

```
unlink('../mydoc/in&out.pdf');
```

The error said: no such file or directory

Comment: Try escaping the `&` like so: `unlink('../mydoc/in\&out.pdf');`

Comment: if you have a special char in the filename you need to escape this char with \. unlink('../mydoc/in\&out.pdf');

Comment: Then adjust the file path to find it :D And escape &

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete files with special characters in filenames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557047/delete-files-with-special-characters-in-filenames)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape special characters.

```
 unlink('../mydoc/in\&out.pdf');
```

Comment: Perfect!! the error is the querystring that passed, the unlink work well ... I have escaped the querystring in javascript

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply a full path to the file.