# Delete the file which has spaces in PHP

Tags: php

I am not sure what the issue is, I am trying to delete a file in PHP. The file has spaces in the filename.

So here, is what I am doing :

```
$filename = "'" . "files/".$results["filename"] . "'";


if (file_exists($filename))
{
    $success = unlink($filename);
}
else
{
    $echo "Could not Delete the file  " . $filename;
}
```

However, I am getting a File Not exist error. However, I can see that file exists in the folder.

I know it might have been asked a million times, however I could not find it.

Comment: Have you tried echoing out `$filename` to make sure it's the output you're expecting? Also why are you adding extra quotes?

Comment: That code won't compile, since you need `echo "Could...`. Could you show your actual code and clarify what the error is?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557047/delete-files-with-special-characters-in-filenames

Comment: Try with a filename without spaces, if it does not work either, research about CWD

Comment: @BenFortune, filename has spaces. Without extra quotes, it did not work too,

Comment: @www.sapnaedu.in Are the spaces escaped?

Comment: Could the problem be with your quotes? Try: `$filename = "'" . "files/".$results['filename'] . "'";`

Comment: @BenFortune, No, I get the filename from database.

Comment: How can the code you provided give the error "File Not exist"? `$echo`?????